# What exactly does getinstance() do in a singleton?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, singleton

I have come across the *singleton pattern*.
I was unable to understand the difference between

```
singletonobj.getinstance().dosomething() //1st one
```

and

```
singletonobj.dosomething() //2nd one
```

What does `getinstance()` do, that isn’t being done in the second case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `singletonobj` is a wrong/confusing name. Singletons are called on a class basis, like:

```
Log::getInstance().doSomething();
```

and not

```
Log log = new Log;
log.getInstance().doSomething();
```

So this should answer the question, but I'll detail anyway :)

```
Log::doSomething();
```

would force `doSomething()` to be a static method, while

```
Log::getInstance().doSomething();
```

has `doSomething()` as an instance method.

Why use `getInstance()`? Because a singleton, by its very definition, should only have zero or one instances. By making the constructor for a singleton private and publishing the `getInstance()` method, it allows you to control how many instances of this class there are. The private constructor is simply to avoid other classes to instance this class, which would defeat the purpose of this class being a singleton, as you wouldn't be able to control how many instances of this class there are.

```
class SingletonExample {

    private:
    static SingletonExample* instance = NULL;

    SingletonExample() { }

    public:

    static SingletonExample getInstance() {

        if (instance == NULL) {
            instance = new SingletonExample;
        }

        return *instance;
    }

    void doSomething() {            
        // Do something :)
    }


}
```

Comment: Yeah, did not see. Anyway, only syntax and details change. Concept is the same.

Comment: @m0skit0: Still I have one more question, could you pls elaborate why do we need `private constructor`?, where as the body of private constructor is `empty`.

Comment: Private constructor is simply to avoid other classes to instance this class, which would defeat the purpose of this class being a singleton, as you wouldn't be able to control how many instances of this class there are.

Answer (score 9):

Well, technically, `singletonobj.getinstance()` is redundant, because that means you already got a hold of the object.

The call would usually look something like:

```
SingletonClass::getinstance().dosomething();
```

or

```
singletonobj.dosomething()
```

in case you pre-fetched the object - i.e. previously did

```
SingletonClass& singletonobj = SingletonClass::getinstance();
```

Answer (score 1):

It would appear that that the first example is calling a regular method, whereas the second example is calling a static method.

The Singleton design pattern ensures that only a single instance of a given object is instantiated at any given time.  The first example returns said instance, and then calls a method using an instance of an object.

The second example appears to be using a static method that does not require an instance of an object and actually invalidates the singleton design pattern...

Comment: I don't see how that invalidates anything.

Comment: @Joschc1107 - I expect `singletonobj` to **be** the single instance. So `singletonobj.getinstance ()` probably returns `singletonobj` again. Which, while redundant (and showing a rather big gap in the author's understanding of the pattern), doesn't really go against the pattern.

Comment: My question would by why put static methods into a singleton class that don't require an instance of the object?  Perhaps invalidate is too strong of a word, as the pattern can be implemented in other methods.  However, I'm curious as to why one would want both in the same object.  Besides harming testability, would this not cause a heterogeneous mix of object functionality?  It is my understanding that the point of a singleton is to provide methods that require as shared pool of resources instantiated once.  If a method does not require these, does it really belong in that object?

Comment: @ArjunShankar - got it.  Not sure if the question was edited or I missed it the first time, but I see where they're getting the instance from the object.  I thought they were calling these methods from the class definition.  All makes sense now...